# What type of shower valve is this?

Tags: shower, valve, leaking

I have drip at my shower head. I am pretty sure it's the valve cartridge. It's 30 year old house. Anyone know what valve this is?

[image]

Comment: Remember to turn the water off before pulling the cartridge, or it gets exciting.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 2):

That's a first generation MOEN.  You may have to pull the cartridge and match it.  Or buy the 2 or 3 that can match and return those that don't fit.

Often they are difficult to pull out.  New cartridges usually include a tool to help turn the cartridge to loosen it to pull out.

The bore of the valve usually needs a little cleaning with some fine emery cloth or sandpaper, wipedown with a soft cloth and relubing with a little silicone.

Definitely early Moen.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a Moen faucet and the cartridge will look like this or similar. They usually come with a plastic "socket" to assist in the removal. You'll have to remove the clip on top with the hole in it to remove the cartridge. These cartridges are readily available at most home stores. Bring the old one with for an exact match.

[image]